# C#: Adding to a List of Type SomeClass

Tags: c#, list

I have this class:

```
public class Lockbox
{
    string lockbox { get; set; }
    int polling_interval { get; set; }
}
```

In another class I made a List of Type Lockbox:

```
var monitor_lockboxes = new List<Lockbox>();
```

Now how do I add entries to the list? Can I do this?:

```
monitor_lockboxes.Add(...);
```

But it does not take 2 arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But it does not take 2 arguments.

Well no, it wouldn't. It takes *one* argument, of type `Lockbox`.

It sounds like you want something like:

```
var newBox = new Lockbox { lockbox = "foo", polling_interval = 10 };
monitor_lockboxes.Add(newBox);
```

You can do it in a single statement, of course - I've only separated it out here for clarity.

(I'd also strongly advise you to change your naming to follow [.NET conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229002.aspx).)

Answer (score 1):

The following would work:

```
monitor_lockboxes.Add(new Lockbox { lockbox = "Foo", polling_interval = 42 } );
```

This uses the the [Object Initializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397680%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) syntax. For this to work, the properties on `Lockbox` have to be `public`.

Another approach would be to provide a constructor to `Lockbox` that takes the values of the properties:

```
public class Lockbox
{
    public Lockbox(string lockbox, int pollingInterval)
    {
        this.lockbox = lockbox;
        this.polling_interval = pollingInterval;
    }

    public string lockbox { get; set; }
    public int polling_interval { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```
monitor_lockboxes.Add(new Lockbox("Foo", 42));
```